Check relink Makefile
I've a Makefile with a progress bar, but I want to detect when everything is up to date and show a custom message, but the message shows all time. When I compile and when everything is up to date.
NAME =          libft.a

CC =            gcc
RM =            rm -rf

CFLAGS =        -Wall -Wextra -Werror
CFLAGS +=       -g3
CFLAGS +=       -fsanitize=address

MAKEFLAGS +=    --silent

SHELL :=        bash

B =             $(shell tput bold)
BLA =           $(shell tput setaf 0)
RED =           $(shell tput setaf 1)
GRE =           $(shell tput setaf 2)
YEL =           $(shell tput setaf 3)
BLU =           $(shell tput setaf 4)
MAG =           $(shell tput setaf 5)
CYA =           $(shell tput setaf 6)
WHI =           $(shell tput setaf 7)
D =             $(shell tput sgr0)
BEL =           $(shell tput bel)
CLR =           $(shell tput el 1)

OBJSPATH =      ./build/

# *************************************************************************** #

SRCS =          \
                ft_isalpha.c

SRCS_BONUS =    \
                ft_lstnew.c

OBJS =          $(SRCS:%.c=$(OBJSPATH)%.o)
OBJS_BONUS =    $(SRCS_BONUS:%.c=$(OBJSPATH)%.o)

# *************************************************************************** #

define progress_bar
                @i=0
                @while [[ $$i -le $(words $(SRCS)) ]] ; do \
                        printf " " ; \
                        ((i = i + 1)) ; \
                done
                @printf "$(B)]\r[$(GRE)"
endef

# *************************************************************************** #
#       RULES   #

all:            clearscreen launch $(NAME) launch
                @printf "\n$(B)$(MAG)$(NAME) compiled successfully !$(D)\n"

launch:
                $(call progress_bar)

# check_up_to_date:
#   @$(MAKE) $(NAME) --question || echo "Everything is updated for '$(NAME)'."

$(NAME):        $(OBJS)
                @ar rc $(NAME) $(OBJS)
                @ranlib $(NAME)

$(OBJSPATH)%.o: %.c | $(OBJSPATH)
                $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -c $< -o $@
                @printf "█"

$(OBJSPATH):
                @mkdir -p $(dir $@) # 2> /dev/null || true

clearscreen:
                @clear

bonus:          .bonus

.bonus:         launch $(OBJS_BONUS)
                @ar rc $(NAME) $(OBJS_BONUS)
                @ranlib $(NAME)
                @touch .bonus
                @printf "\n$(B)$(MAG)$(NAME) compiled successfully !$(D)\n"

clean:          clearscreen
                @$(RM) $(OBJSPATH)
                $(RM) .bonus
                @printf "$(B)$(RED)Removed $(OBJSPATH)$(D)\n"

fclean:         clean
                @$(RM) $(NAME)
                @printf "$(B)$(RED)Removed $(NAME)$(D)\n"

re:             fclean all

.PHONY:         all clean fclean re launch bonus clearscreen check_up_to_date

check_up_to_date with --question checks if everything is updated (in theory), but it doesn't work.
If I put all: like this the message shows everytime.
all: clearscreen launch $(NAME)
    @$(MAKE) $(NAME) --question && echo "$(NAME) is updated." || echo "Update completed for $(NAME)."
    @printf "\n$(B)$(MAG)$(NAME) compiled successfully !$(D)\n"

I've been trying and I can't solve it.

That's not how make works.  If everything is up to date, make prints "Nothing to be done".  That's what every programmer in the world expects.

Hacking your Makefile to display a progress bar seems like a supremely bad use of your time anyway. If you want a progress bar, maybe build the logic around make and let it do its primary job without these fugly distractions.

Sure, it will always show up to date because the all target is run last, after all the other targets, so by the time the recipe for all is invoked all the other targets have been built and everything is now up to date.
